# UIButton not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a view controller in which I've programmatically created a view with several buttons in it to act as a menu of sorts. This view is initialzed with coordinates off screen (y origin of -100 for example). If I adjust the y origin of the view (with animation) the view slides in nicely and I'm able to touch the buttons and have them do as I wish. If however, I adjust the y origin of the view controller's view frame, the buttons in the view no longer recognize the touch. I discovered that by adjusting the view controller's view frame origin instead of the view's origin, I'm able to get the effect of the whole screen sliding down to reveal the menu instead of the menu sliding into place, it pulls it down almost. But the menu is no longer functional.

Anybody have any insight into this?

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep on top of that now that I know.

Comment: If your menu is out side the superview's bounds, it wont detect touches. Make sure it is parents views are also in screen and none of the views have frame set with negative values when you are touching.

Comment: By virtue of adjusting the view controller's view frame y origin to say 100 (if my menu view was initialized at -100), it pulls the menu into view so the menu would now reside at y coordinate 0. Or is that not actually the case unless I specifically adjust the menu view's coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before a long time ago. I remember I had a view controller that's the size of 800x800 points with a button outside the visible view at coordinates 600,600. I animated the controller so that the button shows on screen. Touches to the button were ignored. 
Basically anything outside of the superview's 320x480 bounds, the touches get ignored, despite animating the view controller into place.

Comment: Our issues are similar but not quite the same. If I animate the menu view into place, it works fine for me. BUT, if I animate view controller's view to move down the screen, which seems to also pull down the menu view, then it doesn't. It's as if unless I specifically pull that view into place, it won't receive the touch events.